# Deploy stambol war file from jetty

Tags: java, war, embedded-jetty, apache-stanbol

I am trying to deploy an apache stanbol .war file using jetty.

The server runs, but all I get is 404 errors when I try to reach it.

Curious thing is, the ContextPath gives me a slightly different 404 (without the ':' after 404)

This leads me to believe that it's at least partially working.

I'm not sure how to get this working. Please advise.

```
package my.package;

import org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;

public class SimpleJetty {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // Create a basic jetty server object that will listen on port 8080. Note that if you set this to port 0 then
        // a randomly available port will be assigned that you can either look in the logs for the port,
        // or programmatically obtain it for use in test cases.
        Server server = new Server(8080);

        // Setup JMX
        MBeanContainer mbContainer=new MBeanContainer(ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());
        server.addBean(mbContainer);

        // The WebAppContext is the entity that controls the environment in which a web application lives and
        // breathes. In this example the context path is being set to "/" so it is suitable for serving root context
        // requests and then we see it setting the location of the war. A whole host of other configurations are
        // available, ranging from configuring to support annotation scanning in the webapp (through
        // PlusConfiguration) to choosing where the webapp will unpack itself.
        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setContextPath("/stanbol");

        webapp.setWar("./dir/to/stanbol.war");

        // A WebAppContext is a ContextHandler as well so it needs to be set to the server so it is aware of where to
        // send the appropriate requests.
        server.setHandler(webapp);

        // Configure a LoginService
        // Since this example is for our test webapp, we need to setup a LoginService so this shows how to create a
        // very simple hashmap based one. The name of the LoginService needs to correspond to what is configured in
        // the webapp's web.xml and since it has a lifecycle of its own we register it as a bean with the Jetty
        // server object so it can be started and stopped according to the lifecycle of the server itself.

        // Start things up! By using the server.join() the server thread will join with the current thread.
        // See "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()" for more details.
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Need more information.  For example, what is the URL you hit when you see the 404?

Comment: every url as I stated, only the context path gives me another 404, leading me to believe it's not properly deployed. When I just deploy the war file it works as it should (so it's not the war file)